# Fixing the value of a variable which comes from Random module for the whole code

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to fix the value of text for the whole code and refresh it when the website is reloaded. The value of text is keep on changing.

```
import streamlit as st
import random

word_list = ['tuple' , 'global' , 'list' , 'dict' , 'string' , 'elif' , 'else' , 'while' , 'for' , 'import' , 'from' , 'def' , 'try' , 'except' , 'finally']

def random_word():
    
    final_word = random.choice(word_list)
    return final_word

st.set_page_config("Hangman for Python Programmers")

st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Python Hangman</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)


st.write("Enter the blanks with a Python Keyword")

c = st.container()
st.write("Fill letters here")

text = random_word()
```

Comment: You use random so the value will change. Tell us more about your problem.

Comment: It's a hangman game for python programmers where you need to guess the word which is a python keyword. I have stored the words in word_list and using random module select a random word from the list, the problem is that the random word gets updated when I start entering the letters. Is that possible to keep that one random word fixed for the whole code runtime and not update it every time ?

Comment: You can save the text to session_state. Read it at https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state

Comment: Could you please explain how could I store 'text' in session_state, I can't figure it out from the API references.